# Find minimum and maximum in a string with spaces

Tags: python

I've made a function that outputs the highest and lowest values from a string containing a space-separated list of numbers.

For example, if given `"123 956 334 421 -543"`, my function returns `123, -543`.

```
  def high_and_low(numbers):

    m = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]
    h = max(m)
    n = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]
    l = min(n)

    return h, l

r = high_and_low(input("Enter numbers: "))
print(r[0], r[1])
```

Comment: Why do you need to do `n = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]` a second time? Won't be `l = min(m)` just fine?

Comment: Why is `123` the maximum?  Isn't `956`, `334`, and `421` all larger?

Comment: not easier on the coder: [min&max with no more than 1.5n comparisons](http://pythonfiddle.com/minmax/)

Comment: I agree with @AJNeufeld, this doesn’t make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

### Duplicate Code

These lines of code:

```
    m = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]
    n = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]
```

assign the same result to the variables `m` and `n`.  This results in double the needed work being performed.  The `numbers` string is being split twice, and all the terms are being converted from strings to integers twice.

You only need the first line:

```
    m = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]
```

Or expressed more functionally:

```
    m = list(map(int, numbers.split()))
```

### Directly return values

You do not need to assign values to variables before returning them.  You can simply return the calculations:

```
    return max(m), min(m)
```

### Variable Names

`m`, `h`, `n`, and `l` are terrible variable names.  They convey almost no meaning.  The reader might be able to guess `h` represents the high value, and `l` represents the low value, but make it easier on them; use `low` and `high` as the variable names.  Perhaps `nums` or `values` instead of `m`.  As mentioned above, `n` is not needed.

### Reworked code

Here is one possible refactoring of your `high_and_low` function:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):

    values = list(map(int, numbers.split()))
    return max(values), min(values)
```

### Type Hints and Docstrings

You can additionally help the reader (and method caller) by providing type hints and docstrings:

```
from typing import Tuple

def high_and_low(numbers: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Parse a string of space separated integers and return the
    highest and lowest integers found in the string.

    >>> high_and_low("123 956 334 421 -543")
    (956, -543)
    """

    values = list(map(int, numbers.split()))
    return max(values), min(values)
```

In a Python REPL, the user can type `help(high_and_low)` to get usage information for the function (the `"""docstring"""` of the function).

The Python `doctest` module can extract `>>>` lines from the `"""docstring"""` and execute them, and compare the output with the line(s) which follow, to ensure the function behaves as described.

```
aneufeld$ python3.8 -m doctest -v high_and_low.py 
Trying:
    high_and_low("123 956 334 421 -543")
Expecting:
    (956, -543)
ok
1 items had no tests:
    high_and_low
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in high_and_low.high_and_low
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: Why the `list(map())` instead of a clean and pythonic list comprehension? Aside from that, nice solution! Good to see people encouraging the use of type annotations and tests.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Because it was 2 characters shorter :-)  Some people prefer functional programming. I showed the list compression version and the functional version two lines apart; I was not advocating (strongly) for one over the other.